# How to detect the modifier key on mouse click

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, mouseclick-event, modifier-key

I have a `QTableWidget` and would like that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while clicking on a column header, marks the whole column.

To get the column index is not a problem, since there is a `sectionPressed` signal, which gives me the current index of the column clicked.

How can I get the state of any keyboard modifiers when a column is clicked?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

On Qt 4, try [`QApplication::keyboardModifiers()`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#keyboardModifiers).

The Qt 5 and Qt 6 equivalent is [`QGuiApplication::keyboardModifiers()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qguiapplication.html#keyboardModifiers).

Answer (score 13):

If you are want to know the modifiers key state from a mouse click event, you can use [QGuiApplication::keyboardModifiers()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#keyboardModifiers) which will retrieve the key state during the last mouse event:

```cpp
if(QGuiApplication::keyboardModifiers().testFlag(Qt::ControlModifier)) {
    // Do a few things
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to query explicitly the modifiers state you should use [QGuiApplication::queryKeyboardModifiers()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#queryKeyboardModifiers). This might be required in other use case like detecting a modifier key during the application startup.

Answer (score 11):

From [Qt Documentation — QMouseEvent Class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmouseevent.html):

> The state of the keyboard modifier keys can be found by calling the modifiers() function, inherited from QInputEvent.

Answer (score 4):

I have to install an `eventFilter` and remove the `sectionPressed` handler:

```cpp
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->viewport()->installEventFilter(this);
```

Within the `eventFilter`, I can check whether a key was pressed like so:

```cpp
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
        if(Qt::ControlModifier == QApplication::keyboardModifiers())
        {
            QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event);
            if(mouseEvent)
            {
                if(mouseEvent->button()== Qt::LeftButton)
                {
                    ui->tableWidget->selectColumn(ui->tableWidget->itemAt(mouseEvent->pos())->column());
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return QWidget::eventFilter(object,event);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```cpp
if (QApplication::keyboardModifiers().testFlag(Qt::ControlModifier) == true) {
```