# How to check if CTRL and SHIFT are pressed simultaneously in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt4, keyboard-shortcuts

I found a lot of examples how to get key modifiers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772595/how-to-check-if-a-key-modifier-is-pressed-shift-ctrl-alt). But I don't get it working for checking if they are pressed and hold at the same time.

This should be rather easy, as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> are standard key combinations.

From the above linked example:

```
modifiers = QtGui.QApplication.keyboardModifiers()
if modifiers == QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier:
    print('Shift+Click')
elif modifiers == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:
    print('Control+Click')
else:
    print('Click')
```

We see that either <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> are tested for. But I need a check which finds if both are pressed at the same time.

I tested lots of variants like this one:

```
if modifiers == (QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier and QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier):
```

I found something written in C but I don't seem to be able to translate it.

Comment: The modifiiers can be OR'd together (I updated my answer that you linked to).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My Python is rusty but try
`if (modifiers & QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier) and (modifiers & QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier):`

This checks if both Control and Shift bitfields are set in `modifiers`.