# How I can capture in Python the Ctrl key (only Ctrl, without another at the same time) when pressed?

Tags: python

I need to detect, in a python console (text mode) program, when the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is pressed, without another key at the same time. I tried with `getch` from curses library and stdin, but it waits for any key but not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>. I found information in stackoverflow but always referred to Windows/event environment, or pressed simultaneously with another key (<kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> for example) but this is not my case. I have found in some forum that's no possible, but I can believe it.

Comment: Which OS do you have?

Comment: If you were ok with using qt you could use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772595/how-to-check-if-a-key-modifier-is-pressed-shift-ctrl-alt)

Comment: I have Raspbian, in console mode (text), so I think I can´t use this. I'm right?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is Linux-centric, seeing your mention of Raspbian console mode implies a Debian GNU/Linux console system.

If you're really talking about the console, this is possible albeit very hacky. Curses has a raw mode to read most keys, but Control is a modifier key, so won't show up that way. The method I can think of is to read the input device, much like X would. Use `lsinput` to find which device is your keyboard. As input-events demonstrates, you can see events there while they are also processed elsewhere. Among the downsides are that you won't know if the input was actually going to you (unless you track virtual console switching, job status etc) and you need access to the device, as that property implies it might be sensitive data such as a password being entered to login on another virtual console.

It might be simpler to remap what the control key itself sends using `loadkeys`, thus changing it from a modifier to a detectable key. It will still retain its lower level protocol properties (in USB HID boot protocol keyboard, for instance, it will have a dedicated bit rather than use one of typically only 6 slots for pressed keys).

Either way, this is not easy or portable, and won't work at all over terminal environments such as an ssh session.

Comment: Thank you Yann. I'll try this. Anyway I concerned about the problem of portability, so I try to change my functionality. I thought maybe there would be a "standard" method to use in my case, but I see it's more complicated than expected. Thank you all for your time.