# qt : Can I get keyboard like QCursor?

Tags: qt, keyboard

I want to get pressed keyboard in drag/drop work.
I made a process to DO drag/drop in dropMimeData().
So, I can't detect "ctrl" in that process.
In case of mouse, I can get the infomation with QCursor, right?
Is there any way like QCursor for keyboard?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect the modifier key on mouse click in QT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100090/how-to-detect-the-modifier-key-on-mouse-click-in-qt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QApplication::keyboardModifiers() == Qt::ControlModifier
```

Comment: thanks.. "QApplication" has no "keyboard()" :) I can access directly "keyboardModifiers()"