# Ctrl+Left mouse click event capture Qt

Tags: c++, qt

How can one get `Ctrl+Left mouse click` event in Qt widget. I am able to get key event from `QObject::keyPressEvent()` and mouse click from `QObject::mousePressEvent()`. But I need to capture both in the same function. Can someone give some pointer to right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use an additional variable, like:

```
private:
    bool ctrlIsPressed = false;

protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) 
    { 
        if( event->key() == Qt::Key_Control ) 
           ctrlIsPressed = true; 
    }
    void keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
    { 
        if( event->key() == Qt::Key_Control ) 
           ctrlIsPressed = false; 
    }

    void mousePressEvent()
    {
        if( ctrlIsPressed )
            // ... Your code
    }
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to avoid this, but it could be done this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can call [QMouseEvent::modifiers()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputevent.html#modifiers) to check whether it returns the value [Qt::ControlModifier](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#KeyboardModifier-enum).

Answer (score 1):

Check out this Stackoverflow.com question. I think it is exactly the issue you are having.

[How to detect the modifier key on mouse click in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100090/how-to-detect-the-modifier-key-on-mouse-click-in-qt)